# PhpStorm new line adds space

Tags: html, css

So new to PhpStorm 10.0 and have an issue with "new line". To keep my text clean, I like to format the code like so

`<a href="javascript:;">Link One</a>
<a href="javascript:;">Link Two</a>`

When displayed on the screen, of course there is a space

`Link One Link Two`

So, I did not add space, and would like this to be

`Link OneLink Two`

Why? Because if I add a border around my `<a>` tag, there is not break between my right and left border.

I started getting this issue with PhpStorm, other editors would add space if I did <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> or added actual space between the two.

What gives? Is there a setting I could do to fix this?

Comment: this isn't phpstorm it's just whitespace in html

Comment: Hmmm - I have no whitespace at all in any of the classes in my CSS. How do you suggest this gets fixed?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ found this - but it can't be that this is the only solution???? Is it?

Comment: Prfff - you are right in sense that this is not PHPStorm, but CSS and inline-block ... so I trciked it with font-size: 0 on parent and then size on a tag ... not what I wanted to do, but it works. Thanks Dale.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a Phpstorm problem. It's a CSS problem. By default, anchor elements are have display: inline, so they are by default spaced out. Try to add this css to achieve what you need:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left; }
```